# ConnMan: how to store password as hash?

Tags: networking, wifi, encryption, hashsum, connman

We are looking for a way to get ConnMan to hash passwords (hashed on disk, i.e. not in plain text).

We are wondering if it is possible to enable such feature by compile-time definition or runtime flags

Could you please advise us on this?

Comment: Being connman in the git.kernel.org repo, I'm looking for someone with the knowledge in the matter of connman and secure password storage on the device.

Answer (score 0):

As of 06/2020, and after reviewing the source code (`git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/connman/connman.git`) this is not implemented.

Note that the clients needs the password as-is, ConnMan would need a patch that implement an encryption system ConnMan with decryption on access function.

This issue is also discussed on the chromium [bug tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=182255).

Comment: I have opened this question after having a look to the bug-tracker you mentioned. As far as I know, connman can be used coupled with wpa_supplicant, which accept hashed password "has:${md4-hash-of-password". Do you know a way to save this password with connman? A way to hash it without encrypt it, which needs a shared secret to be saved on the device, becoming a not useful solution too.

Comment: @fiorentinoing wpa_supplicant and connman are two really different applications, they can indeed be used together but they don't have the same target... on connman purely it's not possible to do encryption, now depending on your appliance you can do encryption for sure but this is an other question that require your appliance details.